Double of a manifold and cobordism
I read here the following:

Given a manifold $M$, the double of $M$ is the boundary of $M \times [0,1]$. This gives doubles a special role in cobordism.


What is this special role?
Moreover, is it true that the double of a manifold $M$ with boundary (which should be $\partial M \times [0,1] \cup M \times \{0,1\}$) is the boundary of $M \times [0,1]$?



$M \times [0,1]$ is the identity bordism from $M$ to $M$. Equivalently, $M \times [0,1]$ is a nullbordism of the double of $M$.


Thank you very much


Yes, $\partial(M \times [0,1]) = \partial M \times [0,1] \cup M \times \{0, 1\}$. Picture a standard cylinder, $D^2 \times [0,1]$, whose boundary is a cylindrical tube $S^1 \times [0,1]$ together with the disks on either end, $D^2 \times \{0, 1\}$


But how can I see it is the double of $M$? Don't I need to identify the two boundaries of $M$ in the definition of double of a manifold?

@CrashBandicoot Correct, to be precise this is homotopy equivalent to the double. The cylinder part $\partial M \times [0,1]$ is like a collar neighborhood of the gluing of the two copies along the boundary. If you contracted that down ($\partial M \times [0,1] \sim \partial M \times {0}$) then you get the double by your definition.
